# Why am I getting warning "variable may not be initialized"

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to create a list view using an array adapter, a run method and mutltithreading, but I'm receiving the warning "variable summary may not be initialized" on the following line:         `SummaryData summary = summary.get(position);`. Thanks for any help and please bare in  mind I am new to Android development.

My MainActivity lookslike this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{
...
    public void updateResponse() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {
                StorylineAdapter adapter = new StorylineAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_storyline, summary);
                mEditTextResponse.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My ArrayAdapter looks like this:

```
public class StorylineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SummaryData>{
    private Context context;
    private Runnable runnable;
    private ArrayList<SummaryData> summary;

    public StorylineAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SummaryData> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.summary = objects;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_storyline, parent, false);


        SummaryData summary = summary.get(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(summary.getActivity());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: becoz  `summary=empty` at  `StorylineAdapter adapter = new StorylineAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_storyline, summary);`

Comment: Where are you getting the warning? Are you sure it's a warning rather than an error? Where does `summary` come from in `MainActivity`?

Comment: besides extending the `ArrayAdapter` and using data like `summary.get(position)` ... of course it will kick you in the a** only if you would use filtering ... but if you don't need it why don't you just extend `BaseAdapter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your local variable `SummaryData summary` is shadowing the property `this.summary`. Try renaming one of them to something else and everything will work like a charm :)

Comment: Don't know why someone down-voted you, it is obviously the right answer :p

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work but now I get this in my stacktrace when the app crashes: 07-14 19:00:15.605 29316-29316/com.protogeo.moves.demos.apps W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b8f648) 07-14 19:00:15.633 29316-29316/com.protogeo.moves.demos.apps E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330) at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1128) at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848) ...

Comment: Something is wrong with your `getCount()` implementation. You are trying to access a property of a `null` object... probably the `summary` field (I'm guessing)

Comment: @dbo, may I ask you to mark my answer as correct if you think it helped you solving the problem :)

Comment: Thanks Kirkil, the answer did help a bit but I am still stuck & getting a fatal exception. I was hoping for some further explanation as to how to prevent the fatal exception, please let me know if you can help?

Comment: Here is a link to the current version of the code as a new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414174/why-am-i-receiving-a-fatal-exception/31414399?noredirect=1#comment50803514_31414399)

Comment: @dbo, as far as I can see from the code posted in this question, you are not overriding the `getCount()` method at all. Android calls the implementation in the `ArrayAdapter` class that uses the `objects` array passed to the constructor. If this array is `null`, the `getCount()` method will throw an exception. Also I think I've answered the question that is asked in this thread. If there is a further problem, it should belong to another thread.

Comment: Thanks Kiril I've tried to vote your answer as it did help but I don't have enough points yet. I have started a new question on the additional problems I'm having here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414174/why-am-i-receiving-a-fatal-exception/31414399?noredirect=1#comment50803514_31414399)

Comment: You can mark it as the correct one by clicking the check sign under the answer's rating :)