# Why am I receiving a fatal exception?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am new to android and I am trying to create a list view using an array adapter, a run method and `multi threading`, but I'm receiving the following error:

> 07-14 19:00:15.605  29316-29316/com.protogeo.moves.demos.apps
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0xa4b8f648) 07-14 19:00:15.633 
>   29316-29316/com.protogeo.moves.demos.apps E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
>               at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1128)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>               at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

My `MainActivity` looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{
...
    public void updateResponse() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            StorylineAdapter adapter = null;
            try {
                adapter = new StorylineAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_storyline, summary);

            // mEditTextResponse.setAdapter(adapter);
                mEditTextResponse.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My `ArrayAdapter` class looks like this:

```
public class StorylineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SummaryData>{
    private Context context;
    private Runnable runnable;
private ArrayList<StorylineData> storylineData;

public StorylineAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SummaryData> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.runnable = runnable;
    this.summary = objects;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_storyline, parent, false);


    /*LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_storyline, parent, false);
    */

    //Display in the TextView widget
    SummaryData summary1 = summary.get(position);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(summary1.getActivity());

    return view;
}
}
```

Here is my parser class:

```
public class StorylineData extends ArrayList<StorylineData> {

...Getters/Setters...

    /** ******************* Parser methods    

    /**
     * Parse a {@link org.json.JSONObject} from storyline {@link org.json.JSONArray}, then return the corresponding {@link StorylineData} object.
     *
     * @param jsonObject : the storyline JSON object received from server
     * @return corresponding {@link StorylineData}
     */
    public static StorylineData parse(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
        if (jsonObject != null) {

            StorylineData storylineData = new StorylineData();


            storylineData.date = jsonObject.optString("date");
            storylineData.caloriesIdle = jsonObject.optInt("caloriesIdle");
            storylineData.lastUpdate = jsonObject.optString("lastUpdate");
            storylineData.summary = new ArrayList<SummaryData>();
            storylineData.segments = new ArrayList<SegmentData>();



            /**Get the data associated with the array named summary **To get a specific JSONArray: Summary*/
            JSONArray summariesJsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("summary");

            if (summariesJsonArray != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < summariesJsonArray.length(); i++) {


                /**each time through array will need to get a reference of current object*/
                JSONObject summaryJsonObject = summariesJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);//declare instance of class object ob //array object called getJSONObject //passin indexvalu of (i)

                        if (summaryJsonObject != null) {
                        /**===============Translate data from json to Java=================*/
                            /**Create a new OBJECT OF ARRAY STORYLINE/SUMMARY*/
                            ArrayList<SummaryData> summary = new ArrayList<SummaryData>(); // initialisation must be outside the loop
                            storylineData.setSummary(summary);

                            /**Get summary from json into java*/
                            summariesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("distance");

                            /**Get date from json into java*/
                            String date = summaryJsonObject.optString("date");
                            storylineData.setDate(date);

                            /**Get group from json into java*/
                            String group = summaryJsonObject.optString("group");//Get name using key e.g. date
                            storylineData.setGroup(group);

                            /**Get distance from json into java*/
                            Integer distance = summaryJsonObject.optInt("distance");//Get name using key e.g. date
                            storylineData.setDistance(distance);

                            /**Get duration from json into java*/
                            Integer duration = summaryJsonObject.optInt("duration");
                            storylineData.setDuration(duration);

                            /**Get activity from json into java*/
                            String activity = summaryJsonObject.optString("activity");//Get name using key e.g. date
                            storylineData.setActivity(activity);


                            storylineData.summary.add(SummaryData.parse(summaryJsonObject));
                            Log.d("StorylineDataCls \t sJo", summaryJsonObject.toString() + "Log\n");
                            System.out.println("print distance" + summariesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("distance"));
                            System.out.println("print summary" + summaryJsonObject);


                    }
                }

            JSONArray segmentsJsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("segments");
            if (segmentsJsonArray != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < segmentsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject segment = segmentsJsonArray.optJSONObject(i);

                    if (segment != null) {

                        ArrayList<SegmentData> segments = new ArrayList<SegmentData>(); // initialisation must be outside the loop
                        storylineData.setSegments(segments);

                        String type = segment.optString("type");
                        storylineData.setType(type);

                        String startTime = segment.optString("startTime");
                        storylineData.setStartTime(startTime);


                        String endTime = segment.optString("endTime");
                        storylineData.setEndTime(endTime);

                        /**Get steps from json into java*/
                        Integer activities = segment.optInt("place");
                        storylineData.setSteps(activities);


                        Integer calories = segment.optInt("calories");
                        storylineData.setCalories(calories);

                        String lastUpdate = segment.optString("lastUpdate");
                        storylineData.setLastUpdate(lastUpdate);
                        /**Get group from json into java*/
                        Integer caloriesIdle = segment.optInt("caloriesIdle");
                        storylineData.setCaloriesIdle(caloriesIdle);

                        storylineData.segments.add(SegmentData.parse(segment));


                        Log.d("StorylineDataCls \t sSo", segment.toString());

                    }
                }
            }
            return storylineData;
        }
        return null;


    }





}
```

Comment: Your Stacktrace says "java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)". I don't see the getCount() method overriden in your adapter. Have you tried adding the getCount method and having it return the size of your summary array?

Comment: Thanks but as I'm new to android I'm not sure how and where to add the getCount() method. Could you write an example please.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like "summary" is null. Check for null before creating and setting the adapter.

```
if (summary == null) {
    // handle the error
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error: no result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    StorylineAdapter adapter = new StorylineAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_storyline, summary);
    mEditTextResponse.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as I am new I am not sure how or where in the code I could attempt this. Please provide an example in laymen's suitable for an absolute newbie to understand if possible please?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a getCount method to your adapter. That might look something like this:

```
 public class StorylineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SummaryData>{
//Keep your other methods as they stand
...

@Override
public int getCount()
{
   if (summary!=null)
   {
   return summary.size();
   }
   else
   {
   Log.e("Adapter","Summary array is null");
   return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: He's using ArrayAdapter so no need to overrride getCount(). ArrayAdapter already returns the number of items in the array passed in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks I have added the getCount() method code and now the Logcat displays the message "07-14 19:56:13.371    7957-7957/com.protogeo.moves.demos.apps E/Adapter﹕ Summary array is null" . But the ArrayList summary is not null because I have already parsed and added json data to ArrayList summary in a separate class. I use Log.d() to print to the logcat in the parser class, so I can confirm the parsed data is stored within ArrayList summary and  appears in the logcat above the ArrayAdapter's Log.e() message "summary array is null"?

Comment: The log statement confirms BladeCoders answer that the summary array is null.

Comment: Thanks @wolfaviators & BladeCoder but why and how can it be null if it contains data from my parser class and the data added in my parser class is printing to the logcat?

Comment: I would put a debugging breakpoint in the constructor and see if it is null or not

Comment: I added the breakpoint and debugged and it is definitely null. In that case I'm not sure how to pass the summary ArrayList and its data to ArrayAdapter class, to insure its not null?

Comment: When do you instantiate the summary ArrayList?

Comment: I have amended the code & added my parser StorylineData parser class above. I am a newbie so I'm not sure if I have initialized summary correctly? I was under the impression I initialized summary like this in my StorylineData parser class        `ArrayList<SummaryData> summary = new ArrayList<SummaryData>();` and I was referencing it in the StorylineAdapter class like this     `private ArrayList<StorylineData> storylineData;`

Comment: You're right about how to initialize the ArrayList. The timing might be off. You want to make sure the arraylist is initialized before the Adapter is constructed. You could put breakpoints at both events and see which one happens first.